# Why aren't C++ constructors capable of adding in new member variables?

Tags: c++

It would make more intuitive sense to me if you could add in member variables in the constructor. This way, the class can adapt to changing input.

Comment: C++ doesn't work that way.  It's a compiled language so all object sizes are fixed and must be known at compile time.

Comment: You're either describing a programming language like Python, or you're describing `std::map`.

Comment: where will they go?

Comment: You cannot execute a constructor until you have memory on which to create the object. But with your proposal, you would need to run the constructor in order to find out how much memory you would need. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Is this idle wondering or do you have a programming problem to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ an object always has a fixed size. If constructors can add members at runtime, that guarantee goes out the window. In addition, in C++ all objects of the same type have the same size. Since a class can have multiple different constructors, the different constructors could specify different sizes.

This single, fixed size is the magic sauce that makes a number of C++'s high-performance tricks work, and in C++ convenience often gives way to speed. For example, an array of objects actually holds the objects. Not references to the objects, literally the objects. It can do this because everything in the array is the same size and the compiler can generate all of the indexing at compile time. CPUs love this because access is dead predictable and it can make full use of caches (assuming the access patterns you write allow it to do so). The more that's known and fixed at compile time, the more optimization opportunities the compiler has.

What you can do is add a member like a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` that maps an identifier to its data. If all data is of the same type, this can be as easy as

```
std::map<std::string, int> members;
```

and access looks something like

```
members["hit points"] -= damage;
```

Note that while the map is inside the object, these mapped variables are not "inside" the object, They have to first be looked up in the map and then the data needs to be loaded from wherever it resides in in dynamic memory. This can slow down access considerably compared to a member that is known at compile time and reduced to an offset from the beginning of the object at a memory location that was probably already loaded into cache with the rest of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we add that to the standard. Let's say we decide to introduce new keyword `append` to create new class member from within constructor. Then, one could have a following class:

```
struct A
{
    A(int n) {
        append int x = n;
    }
    A(std::string s) {
        append std::string str = s;
    }
};
```

Now, what is the `sizeof(A)`? Is it `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(std::string)`? Remember that `sizeof` is a compile time operation. Compiler must be able to know that, it cannot be deferred to runtime.

And one more example:

```
void foo(A a)
{
    std::cout << a.x; //should this compile?
    std::cout << a.str; //or should this compile?
}
```

How would compiler know if `a` has member `x` or member `str` accessible to `foo`? Compilation in C++ is done in translation units, with each translation unit being compiled completely separately from the others. If `foo()` is defined in `foo.cpp` and it is called from `main.cpp`, compiler would have no idea which operation is valid. Moreover, both could be valid, just for different `A` objects.

---

C++ has many ways to add some flexibility to amount of members in classes, notably inheritance (to add new members) and templates (to create members of different type in the same class template). There is no need to try to introduce mechanisms from interpreted languages like Python.

Comment: An additional concern is class data member pointers (ex. `int A::* ptr = &A::x`). If you have a class data member pointer, it should work equally for all instances of the class. If the memory layout of a class becomes dynamic, it is impossible to have reliable data member pointers without some form of lookup which is an imposed cost contrary to "don't pay for what you don't use".

Comment: Well, C has flexible array members. `sizeof` simply ignores the stuff it can't know about. More nasal demon potential at a couple of places, but `sizeof` itself isn't a huge hurdle.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Flexible array members are not compatible with C++ for the same reason you can't implement what OP is asking. I believe `sizeof`'s `constexpr`ness would be a huge hurdle to clear. The fact that C found a work around is not any kind of evidence that you could find such a work around in C++. C is not as strict regarding lifetimes and aliasing. In my opinion there is a 0% chance that `sizeof` fails to correctly report the full size of a type's entire memory representation in any future version of C++. There is so much that depends on it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Huh? Non of that has any bearing on the "compatibility" of this feature with C++. C limits the use such structs and C++ could too. You won't encounter "all the places that depend on `sizeof`" under that contract. The only **likely** reason this won't be added is that emplying the feature would be incredibly cumbersome, due to how C++ ties object lifetime to initialization.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Maybe I was unclear. I mean to say that because I don't believe C++ will ever have a second class type for which `sizeof` excludes some of its representation, `sizeof` becomes a huge hurdle. It is my belief that the comity would never consider a proposal which introduces a feature where a type would have the contract you propose as a work around. Since C++11 the language is moving towards encouraging value semantics and such a type would go against that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - I most certainly do not agree with the assertion about value semantics. As one example, the introduction of move semantics (specifically, move-only types as a consequence) is not at all an ecourgment to favor genuine value semantics. But no point going on a tangent about this. We have different views about C++'s evolution. That's fine.